# Android ListView different divider images

Tags: android, listview

In `ListView` I can change the divider image using `android:divider=image` but I want to display different divider images for different items how can I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not have no divider images and make the divider part of the View for each item?

For example, at the top of the view you have a label and an icon and at the bottom you have your divider image.

Comment: I am using custom Listview contains complicated view actually i need divider but in few items i want to replace divider with special divider lines.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no means to have different dividers in different locations in a single list. Either follow Mr. Webb's recommendation (i.e., put the "dividers" in the list items), or keep a consistent divider, or perhaps subclass/reimplement `ListView` to provide the functionality you seek.